# Move view when keyboard appears and hide again when tapped around

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code for the class of `NSLayoutConstraint`. The class helps me to move the view when the keyboard appears. It's fine and it works.

But somehow, when I assign this class to a constraint and the keyboard is visible **buttons can't be clicked, as long as it's visible.**

I experienced it's because I have another peace of code, which hides the keyboard when tapped around - as soon as I remove it, I can tap buttons when the keyboard is visible, but this brings up another problem, namely that the keyboard won't disappear when tapped around.

**Is there a way to combine both, so that the view moves but if I tap around, the keyboard disappears again.**

When tapped around:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Move view:

```
import UIKit

#if !os(tvOS)
@available(tvOS, unavailable)
public class KeyboardLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    private var offset : CGFloat = 0
    private var keyboardVisibleHeight : CGFloat = 0

    @available(tvOS, unavailable)
    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        offset = constant

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardLayoutConstraint.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardLayoutConstraint.keyboardWillHideNotification(_:)), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    // MARK: Notification

    @objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let frameValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
                let frame = frameValue.cgRectValue
                keyboardVisibleHeight = frame.size.height / 2
            }

            self.updateConstant()
            switch (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber, userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber) {
            case let (.some(duration), .some(curve)):

                let options = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve.uintValue)

                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: TimeInterval(duration.doubleValue),
                    delay: 0,
                    options: options,
                    animations: {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layoutIfNeeded()
                        return
                }, completion: { finished in
                })
            default:

                break
            }

        }

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHideNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        keyboardVisibleHeight = 0
        self.updateConstant()

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

            switch (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber, userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber) {
            case let (.some(duration), .some(curve)):

                let options = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve.uintValue)

                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: TimeInterval(duration.doubleValue),
                    delay: 0,
                    options: options,
                    animations: {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layoutIfNeeded()
                        return
                }, completion: { finished in
                })
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func updateConstant() {
        self.constant = (offset - keyboardVisibleHeight)
    }

}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the third party library then please checkout :

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

This library very useful and highly customisable and gets the work done in no time.